problem with distribute 9 bars of chocolate to 3 children
I have a problem with own solution, but I'm not sure I'm right. There are some similar problems on this site, but most of them don't are not very usefull. Can somebody check my solution?
$\textbf{The problem is:}$ How many ways can you distribute $9$ bars of chocolate to $3$ children if

each child should get at least one bar?

each child should get at least two bars?

not every child has to get a bar?


$\textbf{My attempt:}$
So I used the method called "stars and bars" and I got:

I will give $1$ bars to each child and then apply the formular ${n+k-1 \choose k-1}$, so I got ${6+3-1 \choose 2}=28 $ ways.

The same logic is here. I will give $2$ bars of chocolate to each child and then apply the formular, so I got ${3+3-1 \choose 2}=10$ ways.

Not every child has to get a bar means that I have now 9 stars and 2 bars (not sure). So I got ${11 \choose 2}=55$



@lulu yes, thank you, I edited it!

Your answers are correct. I generally solve these questions using the multinomial theorem and it always works.

How can you "generally" solve a stars and bars type of problem using multinomial theorem ?

I learnt this while preparing for JEE. If you can understand hindi, here's the link : https://youtu.be/g-kyYg8Pa5k?si=MSrDEKCd50DFKRnS

Please understand that stars and bars is applicable for distributing identical objects to distinct bins, whereas multinmial theorem is used for distributing distinct objects to diatinct bins.

The video clearly mentions that it is for distributing identical objects to distinct persons. Also, I got the exact same answers for this question by applying it. Apologies though, will familiarize myself with a concept better before commenting in the future. Thanks.
